# How can a user view a list of "on hold" or closed questions?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, privileges, on-hold

How can a user view a list of "on hold" or closed questions? Does this action require some kind of privilege or special trick?

Comment: Everyone can view On Hold questions, no minimum requirements needed.

Comment: Are you asking how to view questions that happen to be on hold (which anyone can do), or how to view a list of all on-hold questions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anyone can view questions that are on hold (which simply means the question has been recently closed). You can search for them using `closed:yes`, or `closed:1`.  That will show you all questions that are either closed or on hold, and you can sort by "newest", if you are specifically looking for the more recent ones.

Note that some questions are deleted soon after being closed, and *viewing deleted* questions requires 10k reputation.

Comment: Note that there's no sure-fire way to search for questions that are *on-hold* vs. those that are *closed*, as the difference is purely superficial as far as the underlying system is concerned.

Answer (score 5):

All questions that are on hold are public.  You don't even need to have an account on the site, let alone any reputation, to view such questions.

Comment: Anonymous users are auto-redirected on duplicates, though, IIRC.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I never knew that, how does it work with duplicate chains / loops? (If you know)

Comment: @Joe: I don't know; from the headers of a single redirect I'd surmise that you'd get an infinite redirection loop.

Comment: Sounds like.. StackOverflow!

Comment: @JeroenVannevel No, because there is no stack to overflow, so it just goes on forever, unless there is a detection mechanism in place (which there is on major browsers, and probably also on SE's end to not cause this situation).